# Makefile to view files that has errors in absolute paths

Tags: makefile

I have the following setup for my project:

```
~/proj -> includes makefile and other stuff
~/proj/headers -> includes c header files
~/proj/source -> includes C source files
```

When executing make in the main tree folder ~/proj errors are show with file names like this:

```
"source1.c" error variable...etc
```

How is it possible to have make show the absolute paths of files in error. Something like this:

```
~/proj/source/source1.c" error variable etc...
```

This is an example of an error:

```
Dependencies for mem_init.c
Compiling mem_init.c
"mem_init.c", line 513: warning: implicit function declaration: init_mem (E_NO_IMPLICIT_DECL_ALLOWED)
cc: acomp failed for mem_init.c
```

Comment: Without showing us the actual errors and telling us what it generating the errors I'm not sure we can help here.

Comment: I added an example Etan.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I assumed. See @MadScientist's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at all, because it's not make that's printing those errors: it's your compiler.  What you want to be asking is how (or if) it's possible to have your compiler show the absolute paths in its error messages.  And of course in order to ask that question you'll have to specify which compiler you're using.

It's possible that if you passed an absolute path of the source file on the command line to your compiler, that your compiler would use that same path in its error messages.  That is, if you run `cc -o foo.o foo.c` your error messages will be relative to `foo.c`, but if you run `cc -o foo.o /home/me/proj/source/foo.c` your error messages will be relative to `/home/me/proj/source/foo.c`.

If that's true, then you can change your make rule to something like (if you're using GNU make of sufficiently new vintage):

```
%.o : %.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $(abspath $<)
```

or whatever.